# How to in insert into a specific schema in postgres using psql pipe command

Tags: postgresql

I have using psql pipe command to copy a table from one database to another in Postgres. It is working fine. But I need to copy the table to a specific schema in the new database. I have gone through the documentation (used -n option for specifying schema name) but it is not working.

Command:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -p 1212 -d dbname -t tablename -Ft | pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -p 1213 -d dbname -n schemaname
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it with `pg_dump|pg_restore` sequence. you need to `alter table t set schema s;` in restored db

Answer (score 0):

I do it that this way:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -p 1212 -d dbname -t tablename | sed "sed/oldschemaname/newschemaname/" |  psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 1213 -d dbname -n schemaname
```

With the corresponding regular expression